# I'm not sure what's wrong with this SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error with the following SQL. Maybe a second set of eyes can see the issue:

Error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE generation_id = 21
>   LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY competition ASC, avg_monthly_searches DESC, suggested_bid DESC WHERE generation_id = 21
```

Comment: where clause must come before order by

Comment: ahh, yes I'm a fool.

Comment: make sure you've read the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the order of clauses. `From` should come before `ORDER BY`

```
SELECT * FROM data  WHERE generation_id = 21
ORDER BY competition ASC, avg_monthly_searches DESC, suggested_bid DESC
```

**More information**

below is the order of clauses in `SELECT` statement in MySQL. Yours could be just a typo. But, this can help someone.

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Causes for the 1064 error**

This error message may seem cryptic at first. it is a general MySQL error pointing to a syntax error of some sort in the SQL Query statement. This error can have multiple causes.

**You need to change in your code like :**

SELECT * FROM data  WHERE generation_id = 21 ORDER BY competition ASC, avg_monthly_searches DESC, suggested_bid DESC

Answer (score 0):

Use "WHERE" Clause Before the ORDER Clause..

So Your Code Transforms to

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE generation_id = 21 ORDER BY competition ASC, avg_monthly_searches DESC, suggested_bid DESC
```